# Mongoose: How to access properties of instance in an instance method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema:

```
var Place = mongoose.Schema({
    lat: Number,
    lng: Number,
    icon: String,
    name: String,
    place_id: String,
    types: [String],
    vicinity: String
});

Place.methods.isInsideRadius = (centerLocation, radius) => {
    console.log(radius);
    console.log(centerLocation);
    console.log(this);
    return true; 
}
```

How can I access the properties of the instance that is calling this method?
I tried printing the *this* but it returns an empty object.

Answer (score 7):

Ah my mistake was I was using the fat arrow function. When I used the function() it already worked.